# Symfony reverse proxy cache Vary on Locale

Tags: symfony, proxy, locale, reverse, lang

I have set-up Symfony reverse proxy, using an eTag. I would like now to cache different versions of a page for each language we support, using the Symfony locale.

How could i handle this?

Thanks!